# Convert svg to some image format in java

Tags: java, svg

assuming i have well formatted svg file - i use foreignObjects and all sorts of things in it - can i have some java code that lets me input the svg string, and gets out an image file of some sort?

Alternatively, gives me a pdf? I'm not really bothered as to the output format so much as just want some simple code that transforms svg to an image.

I know there are things like batik but I cannot work out how to tie it all together.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) is probably the best renderer for Java.  I'm assuming you meant a regular Java application and not Android.

However Batik doesn't support `<foreignObject>` though. It would need to include a complete HTML rendering engine to for that.

To support both SVG and HTML, you would need to embed a complete browser engine.  For example Headless Chrome.